# JOptionPane look and feel issue

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, look-and-feel

When I run my application in Linux with Metal look and feel, the user can't be identitied whether the button is pressed or not. it look like button is not pressed though the buttton is in press mode. also the right hand side close button icon is not same as windows.

how can i resolve this two issues?

EDIT

I did following way.

```
try {
     m_FrameBackground = new Color(Integer.parseInt((String)
          Client.getClient().getProperty("BackgroundColor"),16));
     m_TaskBackground = new Color(Integer.parseInt((String) 
          Client.getClient().getProperty("TaskBackground"),16));
} catch (Exception e) {
     m_FrameBackground = new Color(Integer.parseInt("dfd3be",16));
     m_TaskBackground = new Color(Integer.parseInt("dfd3be",16));
}
m_FuelTheme.secondary3 = new ColorUIResource(m_FrameBackground);
m_FuelTheme.secondary2 = new ColorUIResource(m_FrameBackground.darker());
m_FuelTheme.secondary1 = new ColorUIResource(m_FrameBackground.darker().darker());
MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(m_FuelTheme);
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
```

Comment: can you add some code on how you set it?

Comment: put your code, so that we can have a better understanding of your question.....

Comment: If metal doesn't work: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`.

Comment: Don't use that theme. Instead use JGoodies.

Comment: I would guess this is a swing/awt issue. `JOptionPane` is a swing control, you should only add other swing controls to it. Are you using `java.awt.Button` or `javax.swing.JButton`? Can you add code that shows where you use the button and JOptionPane?